# Will I be able to install Full-Disk Encryption with the Live CD installer?

Tags: installation, 11.10, encryption, live-cd

I'm looking forward to installing Oneiric. But I need to have full-disk encryption. I, along with over 6,800 other Ubuntu users, have been patiently waiting for the [Live CD Installer to gain the ability to setup Full-Disk Encryption](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/24712/).

Will I be able to install full-disk encryption on 11.10 with the Live CD installer?

Comment: Are you aware that you can use the alternate installer for that? That installer is for the advanced user though.

Comment: @Lekensteyn The OP linked to an Ubuntu Brainstorm idea that you should be able to do this with the regular Live CD as well and not have to use the alternate CD...an idea marked as "in development".

Comment: All previous versions allow it … it would make sense that the final 11.10 would have it to.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [LVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_%28Linux%29) is an option. Here is a [guide](http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2011/05/10/how-to-install-ubuntu-11-04-on-an-encrypted-lvm-file-system/) for an installation of 11.04. Although we would need someone more knowledgeable to comment if it is possible to implement that in 11.10.